# Composition of a non-constant function with another function is constant

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Just something I encountered while solving a problem in complex-analysis. Say I have two holomorphic (in all $\mathbb C$) functions $f$ and $g,$ and $f$ is non constant. Is the following implication true?

$$f\circ g=const\implies g=const$$
Considering I know $f$ isn't constant. It seemed trivial for me, yet suddenly I'm not even sure that's really true in every case. Is it indeed trivial?

Comment: It's not trivial. It is false if you do not assume analyticity.

Comment: Say $f\circ g=c$ and $E=f^{-1}(c)$. Then $g(\Bbb C)\subset E$. Since $f$ is not constant, $E$ is countable. But $g(\Bbb C)$ is open, contradiction.